# Custom hash function for Hive buckets

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata, hadoop-partitioning

I need to implement total ordering of output results in Hive with several reducers(e.g.4). As I found by the [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables) Hive is using expression:

> hash_function(bucketing column) mod num_buckets.

And as a result of input set of numbers(41,42,43,51,52,53) the buckets will looks in the next manner:

- 1 bucket: 52
- 2 bucket: 41, 53
- 3 bucket: 42
- 4 bucket: 43,51

So the output will be not ordering in appropriate way.
Maybe there is the way to set custom function for bucketing of number set like:

- 1 bucket: 41,42
- 2 bucket: 43,51
- 3 bucket: 52
- 4 bucket: 53

Comment: Is there a way to define your own custom hash function for deciding buckets?